# Short proof using continuous and differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $0$.

1.) Prove that $f(x)=xg(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ (via proof form).

2.) Briefly explain how/why the continuity of $g$ at $0$ was needed in part (a).

I'm not sure how.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the definition of differentiable at $0$?  (Technically $g$ doesn't need to be continuous at $0$, but at worst it can have a removable discontinuity there.)

Comment: Use the definition of derivative.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if the following limit exists:
$$\lim_{x→0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x→0}\frac{xg(x)-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x→0}g(x)$$

Because $g$ is continuous at $0$ this limits exist and must equal $g(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\frac{xg-0}{x-0}=g$. Let the limit approach $0$, you should be able to conclude the limit is $g(0)$. It might be better to try this yourself.

As Jonas Meyer commented, a removable discontinuity is suffice at here.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.